# How can I write multiple rows to a single child in Firebase without generating the unique key

Tags: firebase, logging

I want to log my application messages to Firebase in a Child call "log". I am doing this now via server sent events (SSE) but I don't really need the unique key generated and I'd like to just expand the "log" child and view all the log records.

Comment: Without any code, it's difficult to help you. Please update your question with a minimum viable code example and JSON representing the database structure you're referring to. Chances are you're using some kind of `push()` method, which creates a new ID, instead of an `update()` method, but again without knowing even what platform you're on, there isn't much anyone will be able to do to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Realtime Database stores all data in a JSON tree structure. All values *must* have a key, and so there is no way to have a list of values that have no associated key. You will at a minimum need to have a key that maps to a string value for each log entry.